# how to use Selenium to create an automatic tool to check mail status?

Tags: selenium

how to use Selenium to create an automatic tool to check mail status? I mean this toolkit could period duly open browser and check in my online mailbox to check if there are unread mails, if there has then change the status as "read" would be okay.

I currently was searching the selenium framework and could use it achieve some basic function, but have no idea of **how to make it auto run and by fixed time interval**. Can someone please guide me? any suggestion would be appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: I know about one test automation site which could do that - check [simpletestIO](http://simpletest.io) However, I did only the simplest test on this site, so I dont know how much is it capable. Also, the periodical checks will probably be paid service..

Answer (score 0):

The selenium standalone jar is executable so you could write a script to run selenium tests that you've created inside the Selenium IDE. It'd be something like this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.8.0.jar -htmlSuite "<path to your .html test suite>"
```

Then, you could schedule this as a cron job to run periodically.

Here are two related questions that might help:

[Run Selenium Test Automatically Every 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769900/run-selenium-test-automatically-every-5-minutes)

[How can I run a selenium test every 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199874/how-can-i-run-a-selenium-test-every-5-minutes)

Comment: Hi dude, thanks, we are now using Selenium+Quartz to achieve our features, really appreciate your help！